# Regex - Has to start with certain characters but can't contain this string

Tags: regex

I have this regex that I been using, but now I need to add something to it.

```
^[|a-z-&+\/](?!\|)
```

I tried a few things, but I just can't come up with the solution.

I want it to add to it, to not match anything that contains a "##" in any position.

These match:

```
|test
test#test
apple
```

These don't match:

```
||test
test##test
apple##
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add a negative lookahead at the beginning after the `^` anchor: `(?!.*##)`.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/fF5kK5/1)

```
^(?!.*##)[|a-z-&+\/](?!\|)
```

---

As [Casimir et Hippolyte points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366983/regex-has-to-start-with-certain-characters-but-cant-contain-this-string/35367045#comment58440169_35367045), since `#` can't be the first character, you could alternatively add this check as [an alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in the existing lookahead:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/qY2qJ1/1)

```
^[|a-z-&+\/](?!\||.*##)
```

**Explanation:**

- `^[|a-z-&+\/]` - Match a single character in the character set at the start of the string (or line if you're using the multi-line flag).
- `(?!` - Start of a negative lookahead
- `\|` - Match the `|` character literally
- `|` - Alternation; or..
- `.*##` - Check for the `##` characters
- `)` - Close the negative lookahead

Comment: Since `#` can't be the first character, I will put `.*##` as an alternation in the already existing lookahead.

Comment: This works thanks. I tried this ^[|a-z-&+\/](?!\||)(?!.*##) which didn't work which prompted me to ask. Thanks much.